# How to import specific column cell data from spreadsheet to populate text document?

Tags: import, cell, spreadsheet, xls

I'm totally unfamiliar with spreadsheets. I can use either Google Docs or OpenOffice/LibreOffice for this. Or even InDesign if it can be done there.

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is print **different Names and Titles** on many different pages of the same paper which already has a printed template text on it. The names are in .xls spreadsheet file in a column "Name" and "Title", and to avoid copy&paste between .xls and .doc file and creating new page every time, I want to just run a script or something that creates for me same page every time, but with a different person on each one.

To be more specific I want something like this:

To: *Director/Administrator/CEO* **[This info I want to be imported from cell S2]**

Dear Mr. **[data pulled from cell R2]**

[All this data in specific place on the page]

**NEXT PAGE**

To: *Director/Administrator/CEO* **[This info I want to be imported from cell S3]**

Dear Mr. **[data pulled from cell R3]**

[All this data in the same specific place on the page]

**NEXT PAGE**

and so on.....

Is it even possible???

Thanks

Comment: You are describing a Mail Merge feature. Search for that, and you'll find lots of info, no programming required. For example, [this](http://www.openoffice.org/documentation/manuals/oooauthors/Mail-Merge.pdf) is a pdf document describing how do do a mail merge in Open Office.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Formranger script](http://youpd.org/formranger)
It should be found at the link I've provided.  I think it will do what you want.